# I have 3 Lubuntu bootable disk drives on one machine, sda, sdb, sdc, how can choose which one to boot from?

Tags: boot, lubuntu

BLUF: I have 3 boot disks on a single machine, how do I pick which one I boot from, or more directly, what do I change on what partition of two of the disks to keep those disks from being the boot disk?

We have 2 identical machines. each is running Lubuntu 20.10. each has slots for 4 disk drives and each has 2 identical 1tb drives for a total of 4 1tb drives. When the machines boot up. the boot device is sda (/sda3) and there are 3 partions, sda1, sda2, sda3. The second disk comes in as sdb, it is unmounted and is unused, brand new. The only differences between the machines is one uses a static address of 192.168.1.104, and the other is using a static address of 192.168.1.105 we'll call them machines 104 and 105.
I figured out how to identify which disks are which so I label the sda and sdb disks on both machines. Now I take the disk out of the 105 machine, and put it in the third slot of the 104 machine. When I boot 104 now, with fdisk -l I can see I have 3 disks: sda, sdb, and sdc. I also see that only sda is mounted, and I also know the ip address is .104, so I know that sda is the 104 machine. I also see that sdc has 3 partitions so I even without it mounted, that sdc is the boot disk from the 105 machine.

I then do a dd clone disk of sdc to sdb.

I then remove the 104 boot disk (sda) and the 105 boot disk (sdc) and leave the clone of of 105 (sdb) in the machine and reboot. I am very happy as the machine boots with IP address 105 (since its a clone of the 105 machine,) and then change its static IP address to 106. We should note that since I only have the one drive in the machine, it is coming in as sda.

I then put the 104 boot disk in a slot, and the 105 boot disk in a slot, and reboot the machine. It boots off the new 106 boot disk, on sda, and the two other disks are unmounted as sdb and sdc.

I do not care about the sda, sdb, or sdc device association particularly, but I do want to be able to set which device is the one I boot from. How do I do this?

Comment: I don't want to install Grub or any other software on any of the drives.  The ideal solution would be something like this:
while I'm booted from the 104 disk, I turn off a bootalbe flag on 105, and turn on a bootable flag on on 106.   I then turn off the bootalbe flag on 104, reboot, and when it comes up I'm running off the 106 disk.   I understand that if I set all three to not bootable the machine will not boot.

Comment: You cannot reboot with a cloned drive plugged in. UEFI/BIOS will see both and it will only depend on which it sees first on which is used. And duplicate UUIDs will confuse boot as sometimes it may boot one and sometimes boot the other and then they get out of sync. What is real reason for this configuration?  Also are systems UEFI or BIOS as configuration is a lot different? Note that Lubuntu 16.04 is EoL. Regular Ubuntu 16.04 is supported until April 2021, but the light flavours, including Lubuntu, are only supported until April 2019. Some parts common to Ubuntu are supported till April 2021.

Comment: FYI: Lubuntu 16.04 LTS being a flavor of Ubuntu had only 3 years of supported life (https://lubuntu.me/xenial-5-released/ http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) which ended 2019-April. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server (no desktop) or Desktop (Unity 7) have 5 years of supported life and are still supported. Refer release notes, or use `ubuntu-support-status` or your own system to confirm this is the case. I suggest you move to a supported release of Lubuntu for security reasons, unless you're off-line or are aware of risks.

Comment: This question can also be found at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2457294

Comment: @oldfred  "What is real reason for this configuration?" these disks will start with a base configuration and then be specialized based on specific requirements.  I am trying to build a test station so that I can just plug in several bootable disks and then control which one I boot from

Comment: @guiverc   I understand.  the age and security issues.  They are irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @oldfred.   I do not expect or care if they get out of sync, In fact I expect them to grow independently like different git branches.   In the old days I would simply flip a dip switch on a disk  that would label a disk master or slave. I want the functional equivalent of that today.

Comment: Site rules say only supported releases (not development, EOL/ESM etc), and Ubuntu doesn't want to encourage people using unsupported or past-EOL software, thus you'll not get much support from people associated with Ubuntu projects, flavors, members etc. We of course are happy for people to continue using our software past its supported life, but you're on your own, and cannot any longer use Canonical/Ubuntu infrastructure (this is an official Ubuntu site).  FYI:  16.04 packages found in 'main' are still supported, so whilst I won't close-vote this question, I'll ignore it, as others may too.

Comment: @guiverc.   thanks for the info.  question changed to lubuntu 20.10

Comment: Lubuntu 20.10 (along with all 20.10) has a somewhat different booting system to older Ubuntu's... in a way it makes it easier; as the boot process is the same regardless of device (where older Ubuntu booted differently depending on the hardware settings it detected, eg. boot *live* 20.10 on any device and result is the same, boot older releases and you see different results on different boxes..) so that is actually a somewhat significant change

Comment: GParted has an option for changing a partition's UUID. This may help with your booting problem. Normally just running `sudo update-grub` from your main drive will add the other drives to it's GRUB menu.

Comment: @C.S.   grub is not an option

Comment: You are severely limited then, 20.10 used `grub` to unify the booting of different architectures and make x86_64, s390, armv7, arm64, etc. boot *mostly* identically, ie. booting the same in all architectures and grub was key to achieve this, unlike older releases which booted differently in different architectures.  Prior to booting of `grub` its mostly controlled by BIOS/uEFI setup which is machine/hardware specific.